# Add two errors to number validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, yup

I'm using `input type=number`and validation to it. 
What I am trying to do:

- if value is not number - show error `only numbers allowed`
- if input is empty - show error `value is required`

`yup.object().shape({ fieldName: yup.number().typeError("only numbers allowed").required("value required").min(0) })`

But it returns always only typerror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to validate an input field or type = number, if an empty string is passed it bound to produce an error. The Yup validation is actively checking if the value is a valid JavaScript number, and empty values or non-numeric strings do not meet this criterion.

1. Use yup.mixed() to allow both numbers and empty values
2. Use the test method to define a custom validation rule

Here's the modified code:

```js
import * as yup from 'yup';

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  fieldName: yup
    .mixed() // Use mixed() to allow both numbers and empty values
    .test('is-number-or-empty', 'Only numbers allowed or value is required', (value) => {
      // Check if the value is a number or empty
      if (!value || !isNaN(value)) {
        return true; // Validation passed
      } else {
        return false; // Validation failed
      }
    })
    .typeError('Only numbers allowed'), // Type error message
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validateNumber(input) {
  if (input === "") {
    return "Error: Input cannot be empty.";
  }

  if (!/^\d+$/.test(input)) {
    return "Error: Input must contain only numeric characters.";
  }

  return "Success: Input is a valid number.";
}

// Example usage:
const userInput = prompt("Enter a number:");
const validationResult = validateNumber(userInput);

console.log(validationResult);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).